Python - How to Override Bloomberg blp.bdp Pull (specifically the YAS_BOND_PX)
I'm trying to use bbg YAS_BOND_PX to calculate the bond price with the spread is changed to 75bps. Essentially replicating YAS  screen functionality.
When I run the code below I receive the following:

Base Data:
px_last BH922181 Corp    86.36
yas_bond_px BH922181 Corp      86.3595
Attempting fetch with overrides: {'YAS_YLD_SPREAD': '75'} Error
fetching bond price with override {'YAS_YLD_SPREAD': '75'}: No data
returned for the given ticker with overrides: {'YAS_YLD_SPREAD':
'75'}.
Attempting fetch with overrides: {'YAS_O_SPREAD': '75'} Error fetching
bond price with override {'YAS_O_SPREAD': '75'}: No data returned for
the given ticker with overrides: {'YAS_O_SPREAD': '75'}.
Attempting fetch with overrides: {'YAS_BNCHMRK_YLD_PREC': '75'} Error
fetching bond price with override {'YAS_BNCHMRK_YLD_PREC': '75'}: No
data returned for the given ticker with overrides:
{'YAS_BNCHMRK_YLD_PREC': '75'}.

So I know it is the override that is the issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
from xbbg import blp

# Define the bond ticker and desired spread
ticker = 'BH922181 Corp'

# Fetch basic price data without overrides
base_data = blp.bdp(tickers=ticker, flds='PX_LAST')
base_data2 = blp.bdp(tickers=ticker, flds='YAS_BOND_PX')
print("Base Data:")
print(base_data)
print(base_data2)

# Try other similar overrides or fields related to yield spread
overrides_list = [
    {'YAS_YLD_SPREAD': '75'},  # Original attempt
    {'YAS_O_SPREAD': '75'},    # Trying an OAS override for price impact
    {'YAS_BNCHMRK_YLD_PREC': '75'},  # Changing yield precision
]

# Test fetching data with different overrides
for overrides in overrides_list:
    try:
        print(f"\nAttempting fetch with overrides: {overrides}")
        
        # Fetch bond price with override
        data = blp.bdp(tickers=ticker, flds='YAS_BOND_PX', overrides=overrides)

        # Check and print result
        if data.empty:
            raise ValueError(f"No data returned for the given ticker with overrides: {overrides}. Please check your Bloomberg connection.")

        print(f"Price with Override {overrides}:")
        print(data)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching bond price with override {overrides}: {e}")


There's an example in the docs here. Other Bloomberg wrappers use a list of tuples for the overrides parameter, but xbbg uses named arguments matching the Bloomberg fields:
from xbbg import blp    
data = blp.bdp('BH922181 Corp','YAS_BOND_PX',YAS_YLD_SPREAD=75)
print(data)

Yielding:
               yas_bond_px
BH922181 Corp    95.xxxx

NB. you can use Python variables, so you don't need to convert the spread value to a string.
